# Trouble using python's random.sample function

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I want to simulate throwing two dices simultaneously. In theory, the probability of getting a pair of outcomes whose sum is even is 1/2.

Now, I have created the following code to simulate this simple situation:

```
n=1e5
outcomes = [random.sample(range(1, 7), 2) for _ in range(n)]
even_sum_count = sum([sum(x) % 2 == 0 for x in outcomes])
relative_frequencies = [(sum([x[0] == i for x in outcomes])/n, sum([x[1] == i for x in outcomes])/n) for i in range(1, 7)]

print(even_sum_count/n)
print(relative_frequencies)
```

However, every time I run it, I get that even though the distribution seems to be uniform, the result of `even_sum_count/n` gets around 0.4 and not 0.5 as expected. What might be wrong?

Comment: `random.sample` will specifically not pick pairs of identical items. So your sample excludes double-1, double-2 etc - those all have even sums, so your distribution is skewed towards odds.

Comment: You probably want `random.choice` which gives "sampling __with__ replacement", i.e. the two items chosen can be identical.

Comment: Quick calculation - there are 36 possible pairs of rolls, 18 odd and 18 even. Using `random.sample` excludes 6 even pairs, leaving 18 odd and 12 even. So the expected even fraction would be 12/30 which is exactly the 0.4 you see.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the earlier comment - `random.choices(range(1, 7), k=2)` (not 'choice' which just picks one at a time)

Comment: by the way for frequencies stuffs have a look to `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your logic little bit. Just take separate samples for each dice and then do calculation. [slothrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765091/slothrop) has already explained the reason in comments.

This will give you desired result. if you want to stick with random.sample()

```py
import random
n=100000
outcomes = [random.sample(range(1, 7), 1)+random.sample(range(1, 7), 1) for _ in range(n)]
even_sum_count = sum([sum(x) % 2 == 0 for x in outcomes])
relative_frequencies = [(sum([x[0] == i for x in outcomes])/n, sum([x[1] == i for x in outcomes])/n) for i in range(1, 7)]

print(even_sum_count/n)
print(relative_frequencies)
```

##### OUTPUT :

```
0.50175
[(0.1675, 0.16579), (0.1669, 0.1675), (0.16533, 0.16674), (0.16716, 0.16595), (0.16601, 0.16708), (0.1671, 0.16694)]
```

Comment: `random.sample(range(1,7), 1)` is a complicated way of writing `random.randint(1,6)`.

Comment: instead of adding random numbers together generate a _single_ random number `random.randint(2, 12)`

Comment: @cards but that would be uniformly distributed in the range[2,12]. The sum of two dice rolls is not uniformly distributed - there are 6 ways of throwing a 7, but only 1 way of throwing a 12. See: https://www.mathsisfun.com/activity/dice-experiment-2.html

Comment: @slothrop you are right! My bad, I forgot about that part. Thanks